# jQuery SVG Element Mouse Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, svg

Been scratching my head for the past hour trying to figure this out.

I have the following SVG inline code and I can't seem to trigger a mouseenter event on a group or even a polygon element. What am I missing guys?

HTML

```
<g id="hall1" class="hallBlock">
 <polygon id="Fill-1" fill="#FFFFFF" points="0.508 83.586 83.957 83.586 83.957 0.501 0.508 0.501"></polygon>
 <polygon id="Stroke-2" stroke="#F5F5F5" points="0.508 83.586 83.957 83.586 83.957 0.501 0.508 0.501"></polygon>
  <text id="01" font-family="LucidaGrande, Lucida Grande" font-size="18" font-weight="normal" fill="#D6D6D6">
    <tspan x="32.9956" y="43.7445813">01</tspan>
  </text>
</g>
```

jQuery

```
var $hallBlock = $('.hallBlock');

$hallBlock.mouseenter(function(){
  console.log('mouse enter');
});
```

Comment: what is <g .. mayb you should close it </g> lol. Make sure the element has a width and height to mouseenter it.

Comment: It seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/gqFdH/177/ . Are you loading jQuery? Any errors in your console? Can you set up a (non)working example?

Comment: @Medda86 whoops, look like I missed the closing </g> in the code snippet folks. Edited my original post.

Comment: It's working just add this in your head section by removing your previous jquery library.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
And when you hover 01 you can see mouseenter in console.

Comment: I forgot to mention folks I am trying to implement this on a development environment on Ruby on Rails.